# How to prove that S = {$(x,y)| y > x^2$} is open?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I don't understand how to do it at all. My professor tried so patiently to explain it to me but I just don't get it.

Here is what he did:

Choose any point in S, say (a,b). The point has a neighborhood around it inside S. Take some point inside the circle (neighborhood) centered at (a,b), say $(a + \delta, b + \nu)$ for $|\delta| < 1$ and $|\nu| < 1$. Now we want to try to do something with this point in order to narrow down our choice of $\epsilon$, the radius of the neighborhood centered at (a,b).

So

$(b+\nu) > (a+\delta)^2$

$b+ \nu > a^2 + 2a\delta + {\delta}^2$

$b - a^2 > 2a\delta + \delta^2 - \nu$

$b - a^2 > (2a + \delta)\delta - \nu$

Then he does something like

$|b - a^2| > |(2a + \delta)\delta - \nu|$

$|b - a^2| > |(2a + 1)\delta - \nu|$

And then he does triangle inequalities on $|(2a + 1)\delta - \nu|$, does some other stuff to get $|(2a + 1)\delta - \nu| < ((2|a|+1)\epsilon + \epsilon)$. He says stuff about maintaining control over our $\delta$ and $\nu$. Then divides $|b-a^2|$ by $2|a|+2$ to obtain $\epsilon$.

Can somebody please explain to me why he does what he does? He really tried to help me and I really tried to understand it but I just don't understand the reason why we pick something in the circle, how to trap $\epsilon$ and pretty much everything. If someone can lay it out step by step, I would be so grateful! By the way, I do know what the definition of an open set is: A set S is open if there is some neighborhood $ \epsilon > 0$ for every point in S.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at your level really, but I'd like to reassure you that this question becomes much easier once you know more theory. It's as simple as saying that the function $f(x,y) = y - x^2$ is continuous, and that the set you want to prove is open is in fact the inverse image under $f$ of the open interval $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: acually, telling there is a neighbourhood around your $(a,b)$ in $S$ is the proof. You could not assume that there is neighbourhood around $(a,b)$. @August

Comment: I gave alternate proof for this in my answer box. @August

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\{(x,y):y>x^2\}=\{(x,y):y-x^2>0\}
=\{(x,y):f^{-1}((0,\infty))\}$$ where $f(x,y))=y-x^2$

Since f is continuous $f^{-1}(G)$ is open when $G$ is open. Here, $G=(0,\infty).$ This proves your aim.

Comment: I don't know how to use that. I'm hoping for an explanation using the method I explained above. Thanks, though.

Comment: How can you take a nieghbourhood for a point $(a,b)$ in $S$.?@August

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think what my prof is trying to do is to show that we can always choose some small enough $\epsilon >0$. But I'm not sure. All I know is that what I wrote is how he approached it.

Comment: I think what August wants to do is turn the intuitive observation that $(a,b)$ visibly has a neighbourhood into a calculation which both finds a suitable radius for that neighbourhood and proves that the neighbourhood is indeed a neighbourhood, using the $\epsilon$-ball definition of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $P \in \mathcal{S}$, you want to show that there exists $\epsilon$ such that $\mathcal{B}_\epsilon(p) \subset \mathcal{S}$.

Your professor is taking the following approach.  Suppose such an $\epsilon$ exists, and without loss of generality suppose $\epsilon \leq 1$.  Take a point in $\mathcal{B}_\epsilon(P)$, and determine the value of $\epsilon$ that will force the point to lie in $\mathcal{S}$.

Such an approach may work, but it is easy to get lost in the computation.  Here is a more "visual" approach.

[image: Diagram]

Imagine a horizontal line through $P$.  This line intersects the parabola at two points $Q$ and $R$.  Suppose $Q$ is closer to $P$.  Take some point between $P$ and $Q$, call it $M$.  Now imagine a vertical line through $M$ intersecting the parabola at $N$.  Consider the axis-aligned rectangle with center $P$ and corner $N$.  The interior of this rectangle is a neighborhood of $P$ lying in $\mathcal{S}$.

---

Alternatively, consider the squared-distance function for the parabola, $f(x) = (a-x)^2 + (b-x^2)^2$.  It is not hard to prove with a little calculus that this function has a global minimum $\delta_\min>0$.  You can then let $\epsilon = \sqrt{\delta_\min}$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $S$ in question is the "inside" of the parabola $y=x^2$. In order to prove that $S$ is open we have to show that,  given any  point $P:=(a,b)\in S$, we can draw a small disk $D_\epsilon$ centered at $P$ which is still completely contained in $S$. The  radius $\epsilon>0$ of this disk will of course depend on the chosen point $P$.

Your professor tried to find an admissible $\epsilon$ doing some computations and chasing inequalities.

Here is a geometric approach:  From $P$ draw a vertical downwards until you hit the parabola in the point $A=(a,a^2)$, and draw a horizontal  hitting the parabola in the points $B_\pm=\bigl(\pm\sqrt{b},b\bigr)$. Note that all three points $A$, $B_\pm$ are different from $P$. A disk with center $P$ whose lower half is contained in the interior of the triangle $\triangle(B_-,A,B_+)$ will then be completely contained in $S$.

Comment: Needs a special case if $a = 0$.

Comment: @augurar: I don't think so. Note that $b>a^2$ by assumption on $P$.

Comment: You're right, I misread your proof.